# Converting dd-MON-yyyy to datetime using Script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

Sorry in advance as I am new to C# but, I have some code for a script component I am using in order to convert a FlatFile column that has dates in the 12-JAN-2013 format.

I am want this to convert into mm/dd/yyyy using this script below but I am unsure of how to go about this. I am using some sample code where Column0 is my input column and my DateOut is my new Date (Datatype=DT_DATE). My new column is just giving me '1899-01-01' now. It is not matching the corresponding dates from the flat file. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
   public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    DateTime varDate;
    bool isParsed;

    isParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.Column0, "dd-mmm-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out varDate);

}
```

Comment: Given that your input date format is clear and unambiguous, you should be able to simply give the column in your flat file connection the DT_DATE type. It will be converted in import and appear as a DT_DATE type in your flow, no manual labour or script components needed. Might save you some work.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing exact ddMMMyyyy which would only parse a string of the form 12Jan2013 (no dashes)

Comment: I went ahead and changed this, to 

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
 {
  string strValue = Row.Column0;
  Row.DateOut = DateTime.ParseExact(strValue, "dd-MMM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 }

but the package now doesn't run, it stays stagnant in the script component.